# Decrypt a binary file in javascript using blowfish?

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, blowfish

Any way to encrypt/decrypt binary files in javascript? i've tried with [javascript-blowfish](https://github.com/agorlov/javascript-blowfish/) but apprently it can only encrypt binary files and not decrypt them (can only decrypt strings).

Comment: Yes, there are libraries to do this. But what is your actual problem? What encryption do you need?

Comment: i need to decrypt a file encrypted with blowfish.

Comment: javascript-blowfish is unlicensed, so you probably can't use it freely in your jurisdiction.